# Ubuntu 14.10 problems with no mousepad gestures

Tags: mousepad

Can someone please advise on how I am to get my mousepad gestures back, when I had windows I had mousepad gestures, like on a tablet but on my PC instead.

I just put 14.10 on, would like to know if any mousepad software for netbooks is available.

** EDIT **

The computer is an ASUS Eeepc 1008HA. It died yesterday, I have to frankenstein it and remove the HDD to get the laptop to boot up only taking it apart is a real task at hand... Will update at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

what is your laptop brand and model and what does it say when you run the command :

> xinput

I have an asus x450ln and cannot use gestures too, I think it has something to do with focaltech touchpads not being supported in linux yet, I get a "logitech ps/2 mouse" instead.